# vector of double[2] error

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, typedef

why this error:

```
#include <vector>
typedef double point[2];

int main()
{
     std::vector<point> x;
}
```

```
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_construct.h: In function ‘void std::_Destroy(_Tp*) [with _Tp = double [2]]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_construct.h:103:   instantiated from ‘void std::_Destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = double (*)[2]]’
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_construct.h:128:   instantiated from ‘void std::_Destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator&) [with _ForwardIterator = double (*)[2], _Tp = double [2]]’
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_vector.h:300:   instantiated from ‘std::vector::~vector() [with _Tp = double [2], _Alloc = std::allocator]’
prova.cpp:8:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_construct.h:88: error: request for member ‘~double [2]’ in ‘* __pointer’, which is of non-class type ‘double [2]’
```

how to solve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do that. As mentioned, arrays are not copyable or assignable which are requirements for `std::vector`. I would recommend this:

```
#include <vector>
struct point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

int main() {
     std::vector<point> v;
}
```

It will read better anyway since you can do things like:

```
put(v[0].x, v[0].y, value);
```

which makes it more obvious this the vector contains points (coordinates?)

Answer (score 4):

The only way you can solve this is to stop trying to do what you're trying to do.  Arrays are not copyable or assignable.

In all honesty I didn't even know you could try to do something like this.  It seems that the compiler is basically freaking the hell out.  That doesn't surprise me.  I don't know exactly why but I do know this will simply never work.

You should be able to, on the other hand, contain a boost::array without difficulty.

```
typedef boost::array<double,2> point;
```

You should look in the documentation to be sure I'm correct but I'm pretty sure this type is assignable and copy-constructable.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give an alternative solution, you can also use a pair of double:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<double, double> point;

int main()
{
    std::vector<point> x;
    x.push_back(std::make_pair(3.0, 4.0));
}
```

But a struct or class named point is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem here. Perhaps an updated GCC (Glibc) would solve the problem?

```
    shade@vostro:~$ ls /usr/include/c++/
    4.4  4.4.3
    shade@vostro:~$ cd ~/Desktop
    shade@vostro:~/Desktop$ g++ test.cpp 
    shade@vostro:~/Desktop$ ./a.out 
    shade@vostro:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: I won't downvote, but there is a problem with the code. Namely that arrays are not copyable/assignable which are requirements for `std::vector`.

Comment: I can't see any compiler compiling this; certainly not GCC

Comment: At one time, before I had a clue, I used to put references in std::vector and GCC ate them up just fine.  I think the implementation simply doesn't stop you until it actually has to use whatever part of the concept is required that you don't supply.

Comment: @Noah: yea, many errors can only be caught during template instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a struct or static array class like boost::array to contain the doubles.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, one can use a std::array; there's no need to resort to boost::array as suggested above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array<double, 2>> x;
    x.push_back(std::array<double, 2>{3.0, 4.0});

    std::cout << x[0][0] << "  " << x[0][1] << std::endl;
}
```