# how to port CArray (MFC) to linux

Tags: c++

I am porting a windows app to linx.
I am trying to port CArray MFC Method to linux.
The CArray to be ported is

```
CArray<double,double> min;
```

I have made an equivalent of this like...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

int main ()
{
        struct values
        {
            double value1;
            double value2;
        };
        typedef std::vector<values> CArray;
        CArray min;
        CArray max;
    return 0;
}
```

but i am getting erros like...

```
vec1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
vec1.cpp:12:29: error: template argument for ‘template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator’ uses local type ‘main()::values’
vec1.cpp:12:29: error:   trying to instantiate ‘template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator’
vec1.cpp:12:29: error: template argument 2 is invalid
vec1.cpp:12:37: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
```

Please if anybody has work on this porting of CArray to linux equivalent, please provide the solution.

Comment: i had checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097445/vector-of-double2-error for making the two values into the struct and then use in vector.

Comment: You don't need _two_ values, the `CArray` class in MFC uses one template argument for the data stored, and the other for the function arguments. If you check the [`CArray` reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2f09ct%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you will even see that the second template arguments defaults to the first. Using `std::vector<double>` is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your struct non-local type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

struct values
{
   double value1;
   double value2;
};

int main ()
{
        typedef std::vector<values> CArray;
        CArray min;
        CArray max;
    return 0;
}
```

However, instead of using struct to hold pair of values, you should benefit from C++ and use [std::pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <utility>

typedef std::vector<std::pair<double, double> > CArray;

int main ()
{
    
    CArray min;
    CArray max;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first line with `error` describes what the problem is:

```
template argument for ‘template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator’ uses local type ‘main()::values’
```

Now, let's think... if the compiler complains about `values` being local to main, how can we fix that? We could, perhaps make `values` not local to main? So the answer you're looking for is to move the declaration of `values` outside of main and at global scope.

Of course, the problem is that the question is wrong: it should be why you need a struct and two `double` values in your `std::vector`? After all, the `CArray` you showed us doesn't hold two `double` values. It holds one so `std::vector<double>` should do the trick. You may find the [documentation for `CArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2f09ct%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) helpful as you try to port this code.

Answer (score 2):

The STL equivalent for MFC's `CArray<double,double>` is simply `std::vector<double>`.